# Do not build Android project automatically on opening

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have been using Android studio for a long time, yet never understood what are the processes that Android studio runs at when we load a new project via `File>New` or `File>Open`. We just load the project and have to wait for so many minutes before the android studio completes those processes (I know that we can still click on file names and editor would open them, but i have observed the android studio will still lag until all those processes are completed)

However I don't know how, recently My Android studio started behaving differently. I don't know what i did, But every time i created a new project, or loaded a previous one, it would show a message like this:

[image]

This was very good for me, because even when i don't click the `try again` 
button, I am still able to access all files and without any lag, thereby removing a need for external file editor. I feel this was some bug in gradle or cache handling that got fixed when i uninstalled AS and updated to AS 3.5 .

So is there a way to manually run all those build and indexing processes, instead of Android Studio just running them automatically?

**UPDATE**:
I think i was not clear before. I **want that error to occur** . Meaning I want to have a control over when the building process starts. Also, I am **NOT** having any error as of now, all my projects are working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Look for highlighted warnings in you Gradle file, you may need to update some things and then sync again.
2. You could also try to clean and rebuild your project.
3. You can also File->Invalidate Caches / Restart if none of the above work.

If none of the above work, please provide more details on what warnings/errors you get.

Answer (score 0):

When version conflict in gradle file, it cant be able to build and sync the project.There may  be show  "Unsupported Modules Detected: Compilation is not supported for following modules”. Fix them too